# How to check session data is fresh or not in Login-session management C#

Tags: c#, authentication

I am managing my IN-OUT login sessions by writing values **0** and **1** into my MySQL database with C# form. Whenever a *STANDARD-USER* logs in, it stores a **0** inside the database and when an ADMIN does that, **1** is stored. Its fairly simple at this point.

The problem arises when any user-group wants to switch during operation.

**Example-scenario**

- ***USER1*** wants to gain admin privilege. He is currently logged in as *STANDARD USER* but he also knows the admin credentials
- When he enters correct credentials session data should shift from **0** to **1** in the database
- When he logs out of admin mode, session data should shift drom **1** to **0** in the database

***Problem with this is:***

- When ***USER1*** has session data **1** and decides to abruptly close the application, now the session data is stored in database
- I could try to flush that data with **0** every-time the login form starts, but that is also a problem as when that happens, I won't be able to know if some call of the login form is its first-run or not (i.e. **I wont be able to know If the login form was called during the beginning of the application or it was re-called for elevating the USER1 priviledge level**).
- If I ignore this, the option to log in as STANDARD USER is open, which allows ***USER1*** to re-login uselessly and also triggers another instance of UserMenu that I do not want to trigger (i.e. two intances of UserMenu are created: one from the initial login and one from the useless login)

> this.Hide();
>      UserMenu ss = new UserMenu();
>      ss.Show();
>      sessionmasterset(0);

***Breaking down the problem further:***
I am having particular confusion and difficulty in some topics and out of the top of my head, I believe these can resolve my problems and at the same time show possible ways to anyone viewing this question:

- Help me solve this problem by telling me a method to know if a form(say) UserMenu() is running or not; and if it is running, then do not let STANDRD USER to log in uselessly as STANDARD USER again -- which creates useless multiple instances of the same form.
- Tell me a method to make it impossible to run multiple instances of the same form

**Point to be Noted:**

- I require a solution in a single form. ie. One login() windows form should be able to handle this all. Please do not suggest solutions that break into multiple forms. (i.e. don't answer with: make a form that only allows login for ADMIN etc.)
- I cannot stress this enough but I am just a **beginner in this**. I would like my experienced seniors/peers to guide me in better login session management procedures too. I am open to alternatives and better resolution tactics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question 2 days ago and I didn't receive any concrete answer. Therefore, during that time, I found a workaround to this. It is a working solution.

I've mentioned earlier that:

> One login() windows form should be able to handle this all. Please do
>   not suggest solutions that break into multiple forms. (i.e. don't
>   answer with: make a form that only allows login for ADMIN etc.)

However, to answer this question(*since this is a working workaround*), I will have to partially follow that rule. 
**I will be:**

- Giving a solution that requires two login() windows form
  (*I realise that THIS violates the first condition of my question*)
- That allows login in both ways. (ie. from any user login session to another; which allows login from STD.USER to ADMIN and vice versa)
  (*But this answers the second part condition of my question*)

### **So the things to do in order are:**

- create two login windows forms namely **login()** and
  **secondaryLogin()**
- For **Login()** form

  - make specific private functions and initialize them at the time when the form first runs.
  - make functions to flush the value from the database. It is always safe to change the default value of credentials to 0, which ensures that STANDARD USER is only selected first(This reduces the risk to allow *possible* ADMIN access from the previous login) 
    [image: STANDARD-USER is pre-selected. Same is default option inside login() windows form]
- For **secondaryLogin()** form

  - make specific private functions and initialize them at the time when the form first runs.
  - Do not flush data from the database for this form. This is necessary because this form needs to be 'aware' about the state of the existing session.
  - In my own implementation, I have used this distinct property of **secondaryLogin()** to toggle the default value of selection. (i.e. If you set the status of the ongoing state of the session in the menu strip, *like I did*, and attach it to a menu item such that when **USER1** clicks it the **secondaryLogin()** form will open, then with this toggle implementation you will be able to intuitively pre-select what  **USER1** wants to login to with the **secondaryLogin()** form)
    [image: A descriptive menu-strip item can be given by reading the state of session]
    *upon clicking that menu-strip item...*
    [image: Similarly, upon clicking the menu-strip item, form will be able to intuitively tell what the USER wants to login into next i.e STD.USER to ADMIN or ADMIN and vice-versa]

**What I realised after finding this workaround:**

- Blocking multiple instances of the same form can be potentially counter-productive.
- Instead, usage of multiple forms such that the second form never calls upon the any other form but only toggles the state of user-session, is more productive.

*I hope this answer satisfies the need of anyone who is having problems with login forms and starting programming in C# like I am*